# Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Date

Tags: java, spring, date, data-binding, date-format

I'm getting this error when I try to input a date in a form.
[image]

**TaskController**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/docreatetask", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doCreateTask(Model model, @Valid Task task,
        BindingResult result, Principal principal,
        @RequestParam(value = "delete", required = false) String delete) {
    System.out.println(">TaskController doCreateTask " + task);

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("/docreatetask in here");
        model.addAttribute("task", task);
        System.out.println("+++++"+task.getDeadline());// deadline is null  
        return "createtask";
    }
        ...
```

**Create.jsp**

```
...
<form:form method="POST"
action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/docreatetask"
commandName="task">
<table class="formtable">
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Task</td>
        <td><form:input cssClass="control" path="taskname"
            name="taskname" type="text" /><br />
                <form:errors path="taskname" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Description</td>
        <td><form:textarea cssClass="control" path="description"
            name="description"></form:textarea><br />
                    <form:errors path="description" cssClass="error" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Deadline (dd/mm/yyyy)</td>
        <td><form:input cssClass="control" path="deadline"
            name="deadline" type="date" /><br />
                <form:errors path="deadline" cssClass="error"></form:errors></td>
    </tr>
        ...
```

In the controller I wrote the following with the same error (and different formats like "yyyy/MM/dd")

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```

I also tried to add annotation in class (as well with different formats) but same error

```
​    ...
    @Column(name = "deadline")
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
    private Date deadline;
   ...
```

Comment: Post the code of your JSP.

Comment: I think, I found out the error. I changed new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy") for new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

Comment: The pattern should be `"yyyy-MM-dd"`. Careful with MM (months) and mm (minutes).

Comment: Yes, sorry by the misspelling

Answer (score 30):

simply add @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd") with (-)

example:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date dateNaissance;
```

Comment: Well, I think this answer is unnecessary since is from 2 years ago.

Comment: but it helped me ;-)

Comment: what should i do in this case "2021-05-27 12:46:17"

Comment: You can also use: ```@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)```

Answer (score 20):

Add this in the controller. Change the dateFormat to your locale preference.

```
@InitBinder     
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
     binder.registerCustomEditor(       Date.class,     
                         new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"), true, 10));   
}
```

Consider using this annotations in your model (Adapting format and TemporalType for your preferences)

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
```

Comment: How does this associate with the pattern parameter of @DateTimeFormat if you need to provide your own DateFormat to the CustomDateEditor binding?

Comment: @ DateTimeFormat might be helpfull if you cast the field to string again. For example. (Convert to XML, Json, etc) or just getting the property in the JSP
@ Temporal will control if you store the field as a DATE or DATETIME field in the database.

Comment: @borjab, thanks a lot! I totally forgot about initBinder... You saved me a lot of time!

Comment: How do I use the InitBinder to register a custom editor for `OffsetDateTime.class`?

Comment: You can also use: ```@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)```

Answer (score 3):

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Replace your format with this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
private LocalDate myDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in BaseController for initBinder

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");   
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, null,  new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, true));
}
```